# How to compare length of 4 strings according to strlen

Tags: c, c-strings, strlen

Write a program that reads 4 Names from the user, and compares the lengths to find the least two in length (strlen). then compares which one of these two alphabetically and prints the first alphabetic ordered one.

---

I have been struggling to compare between 4 strings .. and the result has to be the least 2 .. not just one. The second part is easy, once you find the least 2, I can use strcmp.

For more illustrations, Lets say a user puts 4 names .. Jacob, Alfred, Rues, Reigns. I want a program that sees which are the shortest 2 in length using basic strlen. Any Help?

idk why I got down-voted so fast lol u.u You guys are so mean :P

I tried nested if conditions .. but that was a horrible idea ..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main () {
    char a[30],b[30],c[30],d[30];
    gets(a); 
    gets(b); 
    gets(c); 
    gets(d);
    if (strlen(a)<strlen(b)&&strlen(a)<c)    //Not successful because d is left.
    getch();
}
```

Comment: why not store the length of each string in variables and check which is the smaller

Comment: It is homework. It requires you to try to a) read the lecture notes. b) try writing code. c) Get stuck and ask why this bit of code does not do what is expected

Comment: Please edit your question to include some code that you tried. It sounds like you tried something, or at least got started. If you show us where you got stuck, we can probably get you over the hump.

Comment: A quick solution would be to `qsort` based on `strlen` and then `strcmp`

Comment: First of all, use `int main()` instead of `void main()`  You got downvoted because you were asking us to do your homework for you without you doing much effort. Read [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @ArunA.S This isn't a HW .. this was a test question I have spent hours to solve .. I am new to programing and it really bothered me to not solve it that I am now asking online .. and yes I read those links. Thanks.

Comment: I updated my answer to include a complete example.

Answer (score 1):

Use qsort. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_qsort.htm
It can sort an array by any criteria you desire since you write the compare function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int compare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    printf("compare %s %s\n",a,b);
    int sa = strlen((const char*)a);
    int sb = strlen((const char*)b);
    if (sa != sb)
    {
        return sa - sb;
    }
    return strcmp((const char*)a,(const char*)b);
}

int main()
{
    char str[][100] = { "Jacob", "Alfred", "Ruess", "Reigns" };
    int length = sizeof(str) / 100;

    qsort(str, length, 100, compare);
    int firstLen = strlen(str[0]);

    for ( index= 0 ; index < 4 ; index++ )
    {
        if (strlen(str[index]) != firstLen)
        {
            break;
        }
        printf("%s\n",str[index]);
    }

}
```

Comment: qsort is serious overkill for only 4 entities  this whole project can be done with a handfull of calls,  4 to input the strings, 4 to strlen() to find shortest 2 strings, 1 to strcmp() to determine which is alphabetically first.  1 to printf() to output the selected string.

Comment: Clearly a student is asking the question. Why write a special case for 4 entries when you can learn how to do this for 4 or 4000?

Answer (score 0):

Let

```
char s1[100],s2[100],s3[100],s4[100];
```

be the 4 strings and let

```
int a,b,c,d;
a=strlen(s1);
b=strlen(s2);
c=strlen(s3);
d=strlen(s4);
```

be the 4 lengths.

Then you can easily use if statements to find the two shortest, and once you find them, you know that `a` contains length of `s1`, so if `a` is the smallest, you know that `s1` has the smallest length, so you can implement this part with if statements ( you should try this part yourself as this is a homework question, and also because it's not that hard, so doing it yourself will give you more experience than just copy pasting a code made by someone else )

Then, as you have already said you know how to arrange them alphabetically, you have to implement it.

Well, this is the case for just 4 strings. If you have more, then that is a totally different method ( hint: use arrays )

Here is a simple algorithm that's not too hard to implement

1. Accept 4 strings.
2. store the lengths.
3. find the smallest string ( make the code keeping in mind of the case when the two smallest strings have same length ) .
4. Then find the length which is greter than than it ( or equal to it ) but less than the others
5. Now implement the alphabetical comparing with `strcmp()` with the strings with the shortest length.

## UPDATE

After seeing the code you have posted, it would be easier to store the lengths in 4 variables than using `strlen()` multiple times ( that will help you implement your code easier ).

Comment: First this isn't a HW .. this was a test which I failed in lol
I am very new to programming so bear with me .. 

so after I save the lengths as variables in a,b,c and d.

It will be:
def f(a, b, c):

if a > b: 
    return b 
else: 
    return a
if a > c: 
    return c
else: 
    return a
if a>d
    return d
else 
return a

etc. ?

Comment: @ProgrammerNoob , This might not be the most efficient way, but why not store one of the lengths in a variable called smallest and check if all the other lengths are `>=` the smallest, if not then make that new length the smallest, and repeat ( as I said before, this is not the most efficient way, but it is easier for a newbie to get used to programming by using this hardcode method ). Then, just do it like this to find the second smallest.

Answer (score 0):

How about we give you the idea and you write the code? Sounds good?

So, here's what you need to do.

1. Take input of four strings.
2. call `strlen()` once with each input string and save their lengths.
3. Decide which two strings to compare based on the least and second least length value.
4. call `strcmp()` with those two strings.

As `strcmp(s1, s2)` returns

> an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if s1 (or the first n bytes thereof) is found, respectively, to be less than, to match, or be greater than s2.

you'll have the *alphabatically* smaller (or larger) string.